# socket.emit delay does not work in flask_SocketIO

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio, python-socketio

I have flask_socketIO Python server:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
sio = SocketIO(app)

@sio.on("client_connect")
def client_connect():
    sio.emit("test")
    time.sleep(1)  # Should be computationally complex code: for i in range(1000000): ...
    sio.emit("test")


sio.run(app)
```

And socketio Python client:

```
from socketio import Client
import time

sio = Client()
sio.connect("http://localhost:5000") 

@sio.event
def test():
    print("TEST socket message", time.time())

sio.emit("client_connect")
```

So these steps should be performed:

1. Client connect to server
2. Client sends `client_connect` message to server
3. Server sends `test` message to client
4. Server waits 1 s
5. Server sends another `test` message to client

1 and 2 work, but instead of next steps server first waits 1 s and than sends `test` message twice in (almost) same time. So output of client is (both messages was received in the same second):

```
TEST socket message 1595397405
TEST socket message 1595397405
```

Am I doing something wrong?